# weird if - else if statements but no error...why?

Tags: c++

Help me plz..
I just had my midterm exam and one of the questions was to 'make your own function with three parameters that returns the smallest value.'

I coded for this in C++ as below.

```
int smallest(int a, int b, int c) {
if (a == b && b == c) {
    return a;
}
else if ((a==b&&b!=c)||(b==c&&a!=b)||(a==c&&a!=b)){
    if (a < b) { //a=c <b or a< b=c
        return a;
    }
    else if (a < c) { //a=b <c or a< b=c
        return a;
    }
    else if (b < a) { //b=c <a or b< a=c
        return b;
    }
    else if (c < a) { //b=c <a  or c< a=b
        return c;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Congratz you got -1 point";
        return 99999999;
    }
}
else {
    if (a < b&&a < c) {
        return a;
    }
    else if (b < a&&b < c) {
        return b;
    }
    else {
        return c;
    }
}
```

When I run this in VS 2017, it works but..
if this function is called as

```
int main(){
    cout << smallest(2,1,1);
    return 0;
}
```

I thought this would make an error because there are two else if statements that include this case (else if(b < a) and else if(c < a)...)

It is not allowed for computers to choose which statement to run.. BUT WHY THIS WORKS..??? :( Pretty basic codes but I have no idea..

Comment: So your problem is that there is no error? This is weird...

Comment: So, about 40 lines of code and 200 if/else statements just to find the min of 3 values?

Comment: I see no issues there. Just try to debug it line by line. You will get the idea of it. good luck (:

Comment: It doesn't pick which statement it runs. It goes statement by statement, one by one, as it's written. You could use a rubber duck. You could perhaps also try working case for two variables and see how it behaves.

Comment: @B001ᛦ Exactly. I know this code is crude but works well..........why..

Comment: @Ron Thanks but I was not able to use that,, I had to use if statements..

Comment: @Hexagoner: If you *must* use an `if` then a smart alec would write `if(1) return std::min({a, b, c});`

Comment: @Bathsheba: Lol

Comment: Of course you had to use 'if'. But you did not need 'else' at all. And two 'if' statements would do the job. I hope you can figure how to do it with 2 'if's.

Comment: is there any reason you un-accepted my answer? I dont really care about the rep, just kept an eye on it because i had a serial downote just recently. Maybe there is something that can be improved on the answer? Or maybe I am just misinterpreting the loss of rep and it was for some different reason, then just forget what i wrote ;)

Answer (score 4):

The two `else if` statements you mention are mutally exclusive in the sense that if the first condition evaluates to true, the second one is ignored. Ie:

```
if (a < b) { 
    return a;
}
else if (a < c) {       // if this is true then...
    return a;                           
}
else if (b < a) {       // this condition wont even be evaluated
    return b;
}
```

Also you seem to have a misunderstanding concerning `return`. Consider this code:

```
int foo() {
    return 3;
    return 5;
}
```

there is nothing wrong about this code, it just happens that the second `return` will never be executed.

Last but not least you should consider to simplify your code. Two `if` should be more than sufficient to produce the correct result. Something along the line of

```
 if (a is smaller than b and smaller than c) return a;
 else return the smaller of b and c;
```

Answer (score 0):

The evaluation of the `if` statements happens from top to bottom. Therefore they don't need to be mutually exclusive, and the order of the conditionals **does** matter (cf. `switch`).

Note you can return the smallest value with the simple

```
return std::min({a, b, c});
```

Comment: or without using something from the std library `return a < b ? (a < c ? a : c)  : b < c ? b : c;`

Comment: @Philipp: Which is nice until `d` comes along, but yes, your way minimises the number of comparisons.